# When should [refugees] and [asylum] be used?

Tags: discussion, tagging

[refugees](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refugees) has 55 questions, and a tag wiki excerpt of

> Questions about travel as a refugee or asylum-seeker, as defined under international law.

[asylum](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asylum) has 4 questions, and no tag wiki excerpt.

Many questions tagged with [refugees](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refugees) are about travel by people who've been granted refugee status, such as [Can I travel back to my homeland after being granted German refugee status?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105799/can-i-travel-back-to-my-homeland-after-being-granted-german-refugee-status) and [Travelling through the Schengen area with a Refugee Travel Document issued by the USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46413/travelling-through-the-schengen-area-with-a-refugee-travel-document-issued-by-th)

However, there's some questions about travel being done in order to claim asylum, such as [Am I able to travel to the Netherlands without a visa to seek asylum?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89208/am-i-able-to-travel-to-the-netherlands-without-a-visa-to-seek-asylum)

When should the tag "refugees" be used, and when should "asylum" be used? And do we need to create another tag for those trying to claim asylum?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of puns - I couldn't think of any that were in good taste.

Comment: My interpretation is that refugees can ask for asylum but not all asylum seekers are refugees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it just makes sense to just merge the tags?

There are technical differences, in that every country will use particular terms in its laws, but we're really not operating at that level of detail here, and it varies from country-to-country. We could just use [refugees](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refugees) for any questions relating to people seeking international protection, and [asylum](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asylum) could be a synonym.

Comment: Your suggestion has now been implemented :-)